# What kind of "dash/minus" is this?

Tags: c++

I was copy and pasting a mathematical expression into a C++ script that I have, and it looks like one of the "minus" signs is not registering.

Here is a reduced code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::string str1{"−"}; // note that I copy and pasted this "minus" sign instead of typing it out
  std::string str2{"-"}; // I typed out this minus sign
  std::cout << str1.front() << std::endl;
  std::cout << str2.front() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
?
-
```

They look identical to me, but apparently the former is not a minus sign.

I copy and pasted this code onto several platforms, and I am getting the same output. I also tried in python, and I get the same issue.

Comment: Copying it into google shows its the [minus sign](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2212)

Comment: @Sayse Did you try compiling the code? I want to make sure I'm not crazy here

Comment: I didn't, its possible that your terminal cannot display that character

Comment: Could be an em dash

Comment: Why is python tagged?

Comment: You will be surprised to learn that that minus sign is not an ASCII minus sign, and `front()` gives you the first of a three-byte multibyte UTF-8 sequence of this not-minus character.

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide I tried copying and pasting the same sign into python and it didn't recognize it as a minus sign

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think that's what it is. When you print out `str1` vs `str1[0]`, the output is different.

Comment: Yes, and if you print what is `str1.size()` is, the result will ***not*** be 1.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Right, I just checked that. it's 3. This is interesting. I got to be more careful with copying and pasting in the future then..

Comment: One is U+2212 the other is U+002D.  The U+002D one is useful for C++.

Answer (score 2):

Plugging them into a Unicode lookup (https://unicodelookup.com/) one is a "hyphen-minus" unicode character and the other is a "minus sign" unicode character.

Answer (score 2):

The first character is [Hyphen-Minus](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D)
while the second character is [Minus Sign](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2212)

Try changing your console encoding to Unicode.